# ¿Como enviar una imagen desde ReactJs y obtenerlo en una Web Api C#?

Tags: html, c#, reactjs, asp.net-web-api

Bueno el punto es que ya tengo la parte del front con ReactJs, pero lo que no encuentro es como recibir esa imagen desde el Web Api C# y guardarla en un directorio, en la base de datos solo guardaré la dirección de la imagen

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a [es.so]. Puede serte de interés leer [ask], para que la pregunta no sea reportada como de baja calidad por su extensión y/o contenido.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para poder recibir una imagen en C#, te sugiero declarar una propiedad del tipo byte array en tu modelo.

Por ejemplo:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public byte[] Image { get; set; }
}
```

Ya luego de ello recibes normalmente en el controlador, esa imagen debes luego procesarla mediante Stream.

Te dejo por acá una utilidad que utilizo habitualmente para procesar las imagenes, almacenarlas en una carpeta y resguardar la ruta en mi DB de turno.

```
    public async Task<string> UploadImageAsync(byte[] byteArrayImage, string nameImage, string folder)
    {
        string file = $"{nameImage}.jpg";

        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArrayImage);
        stream = ResizeImageFromStream(stream);
        FormFile formFile = new FormFile(stream, 0, byteArrayImage.Length, "name", "fileName");

        using (FileStream _stream = new FileStream(GetFullPath(folder, file), FileMode.Create))
        {
            await formFile.CopyToAsync(_stream);
        }

        return $"~/images/{folder}/{file}";
    }

    private string GetFullPath(string folder, string file) => 
        Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), $@"wwwroot\images\{folder}", file);

    private static MemoryStream ResizeImageFromStream(MemoryStream originalImage)
    {
        Image imageCover = Image.FromStream(originalImage);
        int newWidth = imageCover.Width, newHeight = imageCover.Height, prevHeight = 0;
        if (imageCover.Width > MAX_WIDTH)
        {
            newWidth = MAX_WIDTH;
            newHeight = (imageCover.Height * newWidth) / imageCover.Width;
        }
        if (newHeight > MAX_HEIGHT)
        {
            prevHeight = newHeight;
            newHeight = MAX_HEIGHT;
            newWidth = (newWidth * newHeight) / prevHeight;
        }
        Image imageThumbnail = imageCover.GetThumbnailImage(newWidth, newHeight, null, new IntPtr());
        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        imageThumbnail.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);

        return stream;
    }
```

Espero que te sirva de algo, saludos